# Django DecimalField returns strings

Tags: python, django, decimal

I have this model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=6)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        ## Following lines are for debugging only
        print(self.amount)
        print(self.quantity)
        print(type(self.amount))
        print(type(self.quantity))

        self.total = self.amount*self.quantity
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What I"m trying to do here is to automatically calculate and save the total value (quantity*amount). This is something I need to have available as a field but it should be calculated automatically. However, I get this error:

> can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

When I look at the print() and print(type()) results... I see that indeed, these fields are strings even though they contain the numbers I expect:

```
982.00
0.008300
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

In the view this is how I save records:

```
item = new Item()
item.amount = request.POST["amount"]
item.rate = request.POST["rate"]
item.save()
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Please show how you created and populated that instance.

Comment: Populated using request.POST values

Comment: Please edit the question to show the *code* for how you populated it using POST values.

Comment: Code added. I imagine it has to do with the fact that the record hasn't been fully saved yet and it therefore has the type of whatever the value is that was assigned, which is a string as it's coming directly from request.POST. If this is indeed the problem, what is the recommended way to resolve this? Typecasting in the model? Or in the view? Or something else...?

Comment: You should use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/), which takes care not only of validating the POST data but converting it to the right type.

Comment: OK noted. Is that the only way? There is a lot of other code around this (code above is just MWE) and ideally we'd not rewrite all of it.

Comment: Well of course you could convert it manually: `item.amount = decimal.Decimal(request.POST["amount"])`

Comment: Great, thanks! This sorted it out. If you post it as an answer I can mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can convert it manually:

```
item.amount = decimal.Decimal(request.POST["amount"])
```

I really would urge you to use forms though. In the above code, if `request.POST["amount"]` is empty, or contains a string that cannot be converted to a decimal, you would get an exception. You could catch that of course, but the form would not only do that for you but also provide a useful error message to the user in the template about what value is expected.